# svg shape nested in shape -- no parse error

Tags: javascript, svg, xml-parsing

I am about to import an SVG into an application (javascript), what is actually working very fine except that their is no parse error thrown by the parser (DOMParser) if shapes are nestet. For example this code:

```
<rect
   style="fill:#393939;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
   id="rect3066"
   width="208.57143"
   height="182.85715"
   x="80"
   y="77.14286"
   transform="translate(0,452.36218) rotate( 10 ) scale( 2, 0.4 )">
  <rect
   style="fill:#393939;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
   id="rect3066"
   width="208.57143"
   height="182.85715"
   x="80"
   y="77.14286"
   transform="translate(0,452.36218) rotate( 10 ) scale( 20, 40 )">


    </rect>
```

does not cause an errors in Firefox. The SVG - Specification for shape elements [here (the path-element for example)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathElement) does not say that it could have any shape-, or container-elements as children. The problem is that the application a am working for crashes if i try to nest graphics, so the parse error would save me from this.

I am parsing the xml-string with firefox's DOMParser like this:

```
try{
            doc = parser.parseFromString( text, 
                "image/svg+xml" );

        } catch( parseError ){
            this.onDone.call( this, "parseError" );
        }
```

If there is any advice how to work around this i would be happy to hear it.

Greetings philipp

Comment: hmm i just tried to open this file with inkscape and even there no error occurs...

Comment: It's perfectly valid XML to do that so that's why there's no error at the parse level. The issue is that the SVG specification says you can't see the result. That's a higer level concept though. After all you could load the data and then use DOM calls to reparent the rect so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not verify your SVG using the w3c parsing service: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Be sure to either set a proper !DOCTYPE property or use the dropdown to force it to see it as SVG 1.1. Otherwise, the file may be checked only for XML compatibility, and, as stated in the comments above, the XML is actually valid.